# GMapping for ROS Melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to use under ros melodic gmapping?

Thanks,

Henne

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327976/gmapping-for-ros-melodic?/) by [Henne](https://answers.ros.org/users/32327/henne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To check the status of gmapping in ROS Melodic, see #q303253 (the procedure, not necessarily the answer itself of course).

For building it yourself from sources, see #q300480.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-07-09**:
I agree with the answer by @gvdhoorn
As I've just stumbled upon this: gmapping has been [released into melodic two days ago](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/72). So it should be available with the next sync...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:
@mgruhler: I've just updated #q300480. Not all of `gmapping` has been released, but it most likely will be (ref the referenced issue).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-07-09**:
@gvdhoorn: you are correct. I missed that the link to the `rosdistro` PR from `ros-perception/slam_gmapping` is actually pointing to the PR for `ros-perception/openslam_gmapping`.